# Is it possible to invoke PHP_FUNCTION from within the extension

Tags: php, php-extension

let me elaborate more on the Title. Consider for example PHP_FUNCTION(session_start). Will I be able to invoke session_start from within session_id which is another PHP_FUNCTION (this is just for illustration not the actual purpose)?

Comment: I don`t know for the others but I do not understand what you want at all friend :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, yes, but you should avoid it as much as possible. One of the main benefits of writing internal implementations of functions is that, contrary to what happens in PHP, C function calls are cheap. Additionally, calling PHP functions internally in C code is relatively painful.

For instance, in the case of `session_start`, you have `php_session_start`, which is exposed by the session extension. Owing to what I described in the first paragraph, extensions will usually export C functions that may be useful to others.

In fact, the internal PHP function `foo` needed to call the internal PHP function `bar`, the best strategy, if possible, would be to define an auxiliary (non `PHP_FUNCTION`) C function with most of the implementation of `bar`. Then both `PHP_FUNCTION(foo)` and `PHP_FUNCTION(bar)` could call that auxiliary function.

Anyway, the easiest way to call PHP functions is to use `call_user_function`:

```
int call_user_function(HashTable *function_table, zval **object_pp,
    zval *function_name, zval *retval_ptr, zend_uint param_count,
    zval *params[] TSRMLS_DC);
```

The variant `call_user_function_ex` also allows prohibiting separation when the argument should be sent by reference by it's not and specifying a symbol table.

This will work both if the relevant function is internal (`PHP_FUNCTION`) or was defined in userspace. If it's a regular function, you should use `EG(function_table)` as the first argument, the second should be NULL and I think you can figure out the others.

If you execute the function several times, this is not very efficient. In that case, see the functions in ["Zend_API.h"](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_TRUNK/Zend/zend_API.h) that start with `zend_fcall_`.

I wouldn't recommend other options to call internal functions, such as manually setting up the arguments stack and other trickery and them manually calling the underlying C function.

Comment: Adding some examples here would be nice. If it's still relevant for PHP 7 and 8.

Answer (score 0):

ie. `session_start(session_id())`

Yes, however in this case it doesn't make sense because `session_id()` requires the session to already be started.